# How to get a list of asian text font?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, localization, fonts

Is there any way to get the list of asian font?
(see http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/61853/FontDialog.jpg)

or how do I know whether a font support asian text or not?

Answer (score 1):

For each font that you're interested in:

```
bool IsFontAsian(Font font)
{
    LOGFONT lf = new LOGFONT();
    font.ToLogFont(lf);
    byte charSet = lf.lfCharSet;
    return charSet == 136; // CHINESEBIG5_CHARSET -- probably also want to check others
    // such as hangul, korean, vietnamese - it depends on what you consider
    // "Asian"
}
```

MS documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145037%28VS.85%29.aspx), see [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/LOGFONT.html) for LOGFONT struct definition.

Comment: Thanks, 
But I found that some fonts which support CJK characters return the charset as DEFAULT_CHARSET, like "MS PMincho"